# How to run bash in detached mode in docker?

Tags: docker

`docker run -d ubuntu bash`
Container will immediately exit. What I need is keeping the container run, and I can use `exec` to login into this container.

In fact, I need do these things in a bash script:

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
docker run -it centos bash
```

But it does not work.

Comment: docker run -ti --rm ubuntu sh -c "while true; do echo foo; sleep 1 ; done"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you want to run `bash` persistently?  An easy solution is just:

```
docker run centos sleep inf
```

That will run `sleep` forever, so the container doesn't exit.  Now you can `docker exec` into it as much as you want.

Comment: I want docker to maintain state between commands. Maybe there is a better tool for that?

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to use `-i` and `-d` together *(I expected them to be mutually exclusive and was surprised to learn they are not)*.

See example output below, I started an Ubuntu container with `-itd` flags, then waited a couple of minutes and ran `docker ps` to confirm that the container is still running.

```
> docker run -itd ubuntu
03c55e9ba9de3e0b80ad9f3e0629dc63f4ab65291b79e133af2b392030ffc17d

> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
03c55e9ba9de        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"         2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                            gallant_hypatia
```

Answer (score 0):

No point in starting `bash` in a container and then `exec`ing into it. You can run `sleep infinity` to the same effect (e.g. `docker run -d alpine sleep infinity`). Because when you `exec`, you start another process in the container. Your `bash` process would be wasted (not used).

In case you want to run an interactive process (e.g. `sh`) in a container (e.g. to be able to attach to it later):

```
$ docker run --rm -itd alpine sh
e2ea4dd1fea30cc91cb27b3bca7d6cbc9718063ef602a02bbea9aa2f7dbf2a3b

$ docker exec -it e2ea4dd1fea30cc91cb27b3bca7d6cbc9718063ef602a02bbea9aa2f7dbf2a3b sh
/ # ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 sh
    6 root      0:00 sh
   12 root      0:00 ps
/ # <Ctrl-P><Ctrl-Q>

$ docker attach e2ea4dd1fea30cc91cb27b3bca7d6cbc9718063ef602a02bbea9aa2f7dbf2a3b
/ # ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 sh
   13 root      0:00 ps
/ #
```

`--rm` makes it automatically delete the container after it stops. `-it` is generally needed to run interactive processes.

If you run `exit` (or press `Ctrl-D`) in the container after attaching to it, the shell will exit, and the container will stop. If you want to detach, but keep it running, press `Ctrl-P Ctrl-Q`.

Comment: you assume the poster wants to use bash that is running, I don't see why that is needed. I basically want the same: an alive container to run sed commands on via docker exec. So anything that would keep the container up, without starting an application would be good for me and I assume the poster. the -id option is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @VincentGerris Hopefully my edit rids the answer of ground for your assumption.